# How to truncate a number to a fixed size without rounding when displaying it with Console.WriteLine()

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to format a number in a very specific way when displaying it, I've tried messing around with String.Format but couldn't find a way to make this work exactly as I needed.

For example, let's way that I have a variable of type Double with the value "123459.7889" and that I want to format it as "459.788" (000.000) but only during Console.WriteLine() and without rounding or changing the internal value of the number. The full value of the number would not show up and it should technically "overflow" the string because it should only print the first 3 numbers to the left of the decimal point.

Here are some example inputs and example outputs:

12345.678 formatted to "000.000" would become 345.678

1000000.678 formatted to "000.000" would become 000.678

1.777888 formatted to "000.000" would become 001.777

99999.9 formatted to "000.000" would become 999.900

Basically, no matter the internal size of the number, the formatted output should always be the 3 numbers to the left of the decimal point and the 3 numbers to the right of the decimal point with zeros to replace the missing spaces if there's any.

I've tried looking at the examples on the C# documentation and found this:

```cs
double value = 123459.7889;
string result = String.Format("{0,8:00000000} {0,8:00000000.000}", value);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But it doesn't work exactly like I needed it to. When running it the numbers are rounded so it becomes 00123459.789 instead of 00123459.788 for example and if the number grows it no longer stays at that fixed size.

Comment: Don’t really understand your example - _I  have a variable of type Double with the value "123459.7889" and that I want to format it as "456.788" (000.000)”_  - why is it 456 instead of 459, is that a typo? - can you edit your question and add  more examples of sample input and desired output and add the specific rules you want to apply?

Comment: Also, what is `(000.000)` referring to?

Comment: @stuartd I edited the question to add more examples of input and output. The (000.000) is referring to the desired formatting of the number when printed to the console, 3 numbers to the left of the decimal point and 3 numbers to the right of the decimal point, even if that means that the whole number would not show up if it's bigger.

Comment: @stuartd "why is it 456 instead of 459, is that a typo?". It was a typo, sorry about that. Fixed it now.

Comment: Do you need negative numbers too? I assume not since you don't show any.

Comment: @IanMercer I do, negative numbers should show up in the same format but with the negative sign: -012.540

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
double value = 123459.7889;
Console.WriteLine((Math.Truncate(Math.Abs(value) % 1000) + double.Parse((Math.Round(Math.Abs(value), 3, MidpointRounding.ToZero) -
               Math.Truncate(Math.Abs(value))).ToString(".000"))).ToString("000.000"));
```

> value= 123459.7889; result=345.678

> value= 1000000.678; result=000.678

> value= 1.777888; result=001.777

> value= 99999.9; result=999.900

> value= 152; result=152 .000

> value= -100.02; result=100.020

> value= 10.0005; result=010.000

Comment: Your solution rounds of the decimal part. For example for value `10.0005` it prints `010.001`. The correct result should be `010.000`.

Comment: @Ibrahim
Thank you for your attention. I edited the answer, I think it is correct now

Comment: Yes it now works and your solution is better

Answer (score 1):

We can use `PadLeft` and `PadRight` to fill up zeros when value characters are not enough.

**Implementation:**

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double value = 1.12;
    string valueStr = value.ToString().Replace("-", ""); // convert to string

    // check if value does not contain decimal and add
    if (!valueStr.ToString().Contains("."))
        valueStr += valueStr + ".0"; // add decimal part

    var arr = valueStr.ToString().Split(".");

    string intValue = arr[0]; //1
    intValue = intValue.PadLeft(3,'0'); //001
    intValue = intValue.Substring(intValue.Length - 3, 3); //001

    string decimalValue = arr[1]; //12
    decimalValue = decimalValue.PadRight(3,'0'); //120
    decimalValue = decimalValue.Substring(0, 3); //120

    string result = $"{intValue}.{decimalValue}";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Result:**

```
12345.678   > 345.678
1000000.678 > 000.678
1.777888    > 001.777
99999.9     > 999.900
152         > 152.000
-100.02     > 100.020
-10.0005    > 010.000
```

Comment: Converting to a string and then splitting on a character that may or may not be the correct one for the current culture is quite nasty. You could just cast to (int) to get the integer value and then subtract that from the number to get the fraction.

Comment: '.' is not the numeric separator in all Cultures, this will fail in some countries. Also heap allocations are best avoided.

Comment: You should tell Microsoft to remove the `split` function if it is not good for the culture. All I did was present a working solution that is beginner friendly.

Comment: If the internal C# representation of the number always as a " . " then It shouldn't be a problem right? I think this works nicely and if there's a need I could change the final string's decimal point to a different character. What kind of culture issues could this solution cause?

Comment: @KTSnowy I have updated my answer to also work with values that are only `int` without the `"."`. For example, `152` results to `152.000`.

Comment: @KTSnowy, Updated my answer to calculate for negative values e.g. `-1.02` prints `001.020`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to convert to string, nor should you rely on splitting on a character that may or may not be the decimal character in the language you are running. You can do all the calculations on the numbers and then format the output without allocating any strings except for the result.

```
public static string FormatNumber(double number)
{
    int first = ((int)number)%1000;
    int second = (int)Math.Truncate((number-(int)number)*1000)%1000;
    return $"{first:000}.{second:000}";
}
```

Comment: The author uses `double` while your function receives `decimal`. This one works but It may be not beginner friendly. You could try to explain better.

Comment: You can also simplify that truncate a bit further... I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Updated to `double` but the op would probably be better off with a `decimal` given what they are doing.

Comment: The 2nd statement can be difficult for beginner to understand, you could add some comments to clarify what you are doing.

Comment: I agree with @Ibrahim it can be difficult to follow and understand exactly what it's doing, but it does work.

Comment: @IanMercer I tried to simplify that a bit further and found out that it returns the same output after I removed the "%1000" on the Truncate() line. Is it safe to remove that, what does that part do?

Comment: @IanMercer Your solution does not work with negative values. For example, `Console.WriteLine(FormatNumber(-100.02))` prints `-100.-019`, it should be `100.020`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static string Format(double number)
{
    return string.Format("{0:N3}", number % 1000).PadLeft(7,'0');
}
```

How it works:

1. Remove the upper digits using modulus (`%`)
2. Format to three decimal places using a [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)
3. Pad left using [`PadLeft()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=net-7.0)

Full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tests = new Dictionary<double,string>
        {
            { 12345.678D, "345.678" },
            { 1000000.678, "000.678" },
            { 1.777888, "001.778" },
            { 99999.9, "999.900"}
        };

        foreach (var pair in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Expected: {0}  Actual: {1}", pair.Value, Format(pair.Key));
        }

    }

    static string Format(double number)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:N3}", number % 1000).PadLeft(7,'0');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Expected: 345.678  Actual: 345.678
Expected: 000.678  Actual: 000.678
Expected: 001.778  Actual: 001.778
Expected: 999.900  Actual: 999.900
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WpiOg7)

Comment: your solution rounds of the decimal part. for example 1212.0009 the wrong answer is calculated.
Expected: 212.000  Actual: 212.001